# LogicApps / Graph API - delete an email from a shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

as per title.
Whilst dealing with my own mailbox is fine I wish to ideally process a shared mailbox in LogicApps. I can read the emails but I want to clean-up by deleting the messages.

Logic Apps doesn't seem to offer that action and unless mistaken the graph api doesnt either?

Has anyone managed this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been possible since the [update on 6th May 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#shared-mailbox-support). A number of the actions now support an `Original Mailbox Address` optional parameter that you can set to access the shared mailbox:

> As of May 6, 2020, shared mailbox support was added for certain operations with an optional 'Mailbox address' parameter, allowing you to specify a shared mailbox address for your operation to access.

The **Delete Email (V2)** action supports this parameter:

[image: Finding the Original Mailbox Address parameter]

You then fill in the email address of your shared mailbox:
[image: Supplying an original mailbox address]

Which will then successfully find your message id and delete the email for you:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, I write a logic app sample for your reference:

Before we start, provide the whole logic app:
[image]

**1.** In first "HTTP" action, I request for the access token.
[image]

**2.** Then I add a "Parse JSON" action to parse the response from the first "HTTP" action to get the access token.
[image]

The schema should be:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "access_token": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ext_expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "token_type": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**3.** In the second "HTTP" action, I request for all of the messages by the access token from above steps.
[image]

**4.** After that, we need to use another "Parse JSON" action to parse the response from "HTTP 2".
[image]

The schema should be:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.context": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "@@odata.etag": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "bccRecipients": {
                        "type": "array"
                    },
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "content": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "contentType": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "bodyPreview": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "categories": {
                        "type": "array"
                    },
                    "ccRecipients": {
                        "type": "array"
                    },
                    "changeKey": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "conversationId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "conversationIndex": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "createdDateTime": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "flag": {
                        "properties": {
                            "flagStatus": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "from": {
                        "properties": {
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "address": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "hasAttachments": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "importance": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "inferenceClassification": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "internetMessageId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isDraft": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isRead": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "isReadReceiptRequested": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "lastModifiedDateTime": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "parentFolderId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "receivedDateTime": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "replyTo": {
                        "type": "array"
                    },
                    "sender": {
                        "properties": {
                            "emailAddress": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "address": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "sentDateTime": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "subject": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "toRecipients": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "emailAddress": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "address": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "emailAddress"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    },
                    "webLink": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "@@odata.etag",
                    "id",
                    "createdDateTime",
                    "lastModifiedDateTime",
                    "changeKey",
                    "categories",
                    "receivedDateTime",
                    "sentDateTime",
                    "hasAttachments",
                    "internetMessageId",
                    "subject",
                    "bodyPreview",
                    "importance",
                    "parentFolderId",
                    "conversationId",
                    "conversationIndex",
                    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested",
                    "isReadReceiptRequested",
                    "isRead",
                    "isDraft",
                    "webLink",
                    "inferenceClassification",
                    "body",
                    "sender",
                    "from",
                    "toRecipients",
                    "ccRecipients",
                    "bccRecipients",
                    "replyTo",
                    "flag"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**5.** Then use a "For each" and loop the `value` from "Parse JSON 2".
[image]

**6.** In "For each", we need to add third "HTTP" action as below screenshot:
[image]

**7.** Run the logic app, it will delete all of the messages in shared mailbox.

**By the way:**

Before run the logic app, you need to search the `client_id` in your azure ad app registrations to find the application and add the `Mail.ReadWrite` permission to it. Also don't forget grant admin consent for it.
[image]